# What is the best way to provide limited teams access to guest users?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am part of multiple projects that uses Teams to manage their information.  Project are composed mostly of people belonging to my company but will, at some point in time, include external service providers, product vendors, etc.  We would like to use Teams to communicate with them, collaborate on files, do meetings without giving them access to all of the Teams' space/areas/artifacts.  What is the best high-level approach to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

After digging into Private Channels we have decided to use that to limit access to company material via Private Channels while leaving General and other Public Channels accessible to all members of the team, including Guest(s).